# Finding critical points of a function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let's say we'd like to find the [critical points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_%28mathematics%29) of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x-x^2}$. Finding out where the derivative is 0 is straightforward with `Reduce`:

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[x - x^2]
f'[x] == 0
Reduce[%]
```

which yields:

```
(1 - 2 x)/(2 Sqrt[x - x^2]) == 0

x == 1/2
```

To find out where the real values of the derivative do not exist, I look for values of $x$ that make the denominator 0:

```
Reduce[2 Sqrt[x - x^2] == 0]
```

which yields:

```
x == 0 || x == 1
```

To do this, I manually extracted the denominator expression from the derivative and ran it through `Reduce`.

My question is, is there a better way to ask Mathematica for values of $x$ where an expression doesn't have a real value? E.g. in this case, I'd like to pass in the expression for the derivative $\frac{1-2x}{2\sqrt{x-x^2}}$, and have it report that at 0 and 1, the real value doesn't exist.

Comment: For even more fun, try it with $x^3\exp(-1/x^2)$ or $x^3\exp(1/x^2)$ :-).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Slightly more generally than the solution by @Sjoerd, you may look for roots of the reciprocal function - if you are interested in pole-like or root-like singularities:

```
f[x_] := (1 - 2 x)/(2 Sqrt[x - x^2])

Reduce[1/f[x] == 0, x]

(*
  ==> x == 0 || x == 1
*)
```

Answer (score 14):

A simple method is to test for reality directly, as follows

```
Reduce[f'[x] ∈ Reals, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> 0 < x < 1
> ```

which does not give you the points where $f^\prime(x) \notin \mathbb{R}$. Alternatively, you can test the denominator directly for reality, as follows

```
Reduce[Denominator[f'[x]] ∈ Reals, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> 0 <= x <= 1
> ```

which taken with the previous result clearly shows that at $x = 0,1$, $f^\prime(x) \notin \mathbb{R}$. Explicitly searching for those points by combining the two equations, though, gives an odd result

```
Reduce[! (f'[x] ∈ Reals) 
      && (Denominator[f'[x]] ∈ Reals), x]
```

> ```
> Im[x] != 0 && Re[x] == 1/2
> ```

despite the results being compatible when the search is expanded to include $x \in \mathbb{C}$

```
Reduce[f'[x] ∈ Reals, x]
Reduce[Denominator[f'[x]] ∈ Reals, x] // LogicalExpand // Simplify
Reduce[!%% && %, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> 0 < Re[x] < 1 && Im[x] == 0
> (Im[x] == 0 && 0 <= Re[x] <= 1) || 2 Re[x] == 1
> x == 0 || x == 1
> ```

**Edit**: in case anyone was wondering, looking for the region where $f^\prime(x) \notin \mathbb{R}$ directly

```
Reduce[! (f'[x] ∈ Reals), x]
```

gives the remarkably helpful answer

> ```
> Im[(1 - 2 x)/Sqrt[x - x^2]] != 0
> ```

However, this does better

```
!Reduce[(f'[x] ∈ Reals), x] // LogicalExpand // Simplify
```

> ```
> Re[x] <= 0 || Re[x] >= 1 || Im[x] != 0
> ```

Answer (score 11):

Here's one approach, though it possibly answers a slightly different question:

```
Reduce[-Infinity < f'[x] < Infinity, x]
```

> ```
> 0 < Re[x] < 1 && Im[x] == 0
> ```

or

```
Reduce[-Infinity < f'[x] < Infinity, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> 0 < x < 1
> ```

Answer (score 10):

For expressions involving ratios you could try `Denominator`

```
Reduce[Denominator[(1 - 2 x)/(2 Sqrt[x - x^2])] == 0, x]

(*
==> x == 0 || x == 1
*)
```

I don't know a method that will find all non real valued points/areas in a general case.

Comment: To answer your last question, just [ask mma](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2508/52) to do it for you.

Comment: @rcollyer Indeed, I forgot that Reduce allows domain specifications as expressions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain) to find out where the derivative *does* have a real value:

```
FunctionDomain[D[(1-2x)/(2 Sqrt[x-x^2]),x],x]
```

> 0 < x < 1

If you must have the region where the derivative does not have a real value, one method is:

```
Reduce[Not[0<x<1]]
```

> x <= 0 || x >= 1